# cURL delete all data

Tags: curl, sharepoint-2010

I know that we can delete records only by reference IDs. What is the best way to delete all from an existing share point list?

Do i need to pass the delete command into multiple lines as shown below or any other easy way to do it?

```
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities(1)
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities(2)
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities(3)
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities(4)
.
.
and so on
```

I am looking for something like 
`curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svcFacilities(1,2,3,4....n) 
or 
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svcFacilities(*)`

Here is the Data in a text file(myfile.txt)

```
Column1, Column2, Column3
A1,A2,A3
B1,B2,B3
C1,C2,C3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
curl -X DELETE http://Server/sites/eTMFDev/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Facilities([1-100])
```

`[1-100]` means 1 to 100 one by one.

Comment: Hi Sabuj, You mean i have to write 100 lines of code as i have explained in my original post?

Comment: @user3230433 No, just this single one will do as the 100 lines of codes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Similary, Do you know a way of uploading data from text file should i give them in 100 lines or i can refer them from text file? What format should i use if i want to pull that from text file?

Comment: If you upload from a same file, then do it normally. But if its from different files, then use `[..]` with the file names to be file1, file2 etc...

Comment: Thanks Sabuj. Your help is much appreciated. I have data as explained above in a flat file. How should my file format look like for cURL upload into sharepoint

Comment: @user3230433 I don't know about the format of the file. You can check sharepoint's API doc(if there is any).